# Kill watch from bash

Tags: bash, watch, mdadm

I need to be able to call this:

> watch -n1 cat /proc/mdstat

from bash.

For raid creating watching (after mdadm --create etc.), and then kill it then building process will end.

```
#!/bin/bash
#PID=$!
while
progress=$(cat /proc/mdstat |grep -oE 'recovery = ? [0-9]*')
do
    watch -n1 cat /proc/mdstat
    PID=$(pidof watch)
    echo "$PID" >> /mnt/pid
    if (("$progress" >= "100"))
        then
            break
            kill -9 $PID
    fi
done
echo "done"
```

But I can not figure out how to kill watch out from bash. I tried `PID=$!` and `PID=$$`, `pidof watch` at the cycle and out of him, but can't assign correct `PID` to my variable to make `kill -9 $PID`.

Comment: As an aside, you should basically never use `kill -9`.  In normal circumstances, just `kill` should suffice.

Comment: In this particular piece of code, the `break` causes the script to exit the loop, so your `kill` never gets executed.  Switch the order of those two statements.

Comment: Note that the watch command is run in the foreground. The script never reaches past the first execution of watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to have watch running until progress reaches 100 ?

```
watch  -n1 cat /proc/mdstat &
WATCHPID=$!
while
progress=$(cat /proc/mdstat |grep -oE 'recovery = ? [0-9]*')
do

if (("$progress" >= "100"))
    then
        break

fi
sleep 1
done

kill $WATCHPID

echo "done"
```

Comment: great! i just can't understand how did you
>watch -n1 cat /proc/mdstat **&**

does not going to background? i tried it but couldn't take watch from background

Comment: @gek I don't really understand what you're asking. The '&' makes the command go to the background. Your code doesn't have an '&'.